# Is it reliable to compare two isoformat datetime strings?

Tags: python, datetime

I need to find out which of two isoformatted datetime strings is the latest.

By now, I convert them using `datetime.strptime` method. 
Then I compare two `datetime` objects.
Then I call `isoformat` of the greatest `datetime` object in order to pass it as a get parameter.

So I'm wondering if it is reliable to find out the greatest isoformatted string without doing converstion from `str` to `datetime`.

It seems to work:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime as dt
>>> s1 = '2013-12-25T19:20:41.391393'
>>> s2 = '2013-12-25T19:20:41.391394'
>>> s1 > s2
False
>>> pattern = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'
>>> dt.strptime(s1, pattern) > dt.strptime(s2, pattern)
False
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

ISO 8601 date strings (without timezone offset), which is the type of string returned by [isoformat](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat),  [can be compared as strings](http://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/iso-time.html).

As [Assem-Hafez points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20774312/is-it-reliable-to-compare-two-isoformat-datetime-strings/20774348?noredirect=1#comment101849469_20774348), if the strings include timezone offsets, then string comparison may not produce the same result as timezone-aware datetime comparison:

```
In [31]: import dateutil.parser as DP

In [32]: s = ["2019-08-29T10:50:35+00:00", "2019-08-29T10:50:35+02:00"]

In [33]: t = [DP.parse(si) for si in s]; t
Out[33]: 
[datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 29, 10, 50, 35, tzinfo=tzutc()),
 datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 29, 10, 50, 35, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 7200))]

In [34]: s[0] < s[1]
Out[34]: True

In [35]: t[0] < t[1]
Out[35]: False
```

Comment: It wont be accurate comparison if dates have different time zones
as an example consider "2019-08-29T04:00:00+00:00:00" and "2019-08-29T04:00:00+02:00:00"
the comparison will show that the second date is greater while in fact it the first one is greater.

Comment: Another edge case is when date strings are being compared without TZ offsets, and they actually are from different regions! Beware.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare two ISO strings directly because of two factors:

1. String comparison algorithm starts from the most left char;
2. ISO string is formatted in a way that the left char is more significant than right one.

Generally speaking, 'year' is more significant than 'month', the first char of 'year' is more significant than the second char, etc.

Comment: Keep in mind doing a string compare won't always work if the timezone component of the date is the different. For example:
2018-05-28T23:20:00.874+0000
2018-05-28T23:21:00.874-0007

Comment: @Mike Good point! Comparing strings of dates is discouraged, comparing dates is favored.